# Trouble managing keyboard focus

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on an application that generates a kenken puzzle, wherein the user inputs number to solve it. However, I can't seem to get the focus system to work; my JFrame doesn't even receive focus to begin with. Here is the method which initializes the main frame:

```
    public static void initMain() {

    mainframe.setVisible(true);
    mainframe.setSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
    mainframe.requestFocus();
    System.out.println(mainframe.isFocusOwner());
    System.out.println(mainframe.isFocusable());

    mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    mainframe.setContentPane(puzzle);
    in = mainframe.getInsets();

    mainframe.setJMenuBar(bar);
    bar.add(menu);
    menu.add(item);
    item.addMouseListener(new MouseListener () {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {popup();}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
}
```

(latter half not so important here, just showing it for completions's sake)

The first output is always false, and key events aren't generated. From what I gethered online, setting the window to visible and requesting focus should be enough, although the emphasis is on should. My operating system is Windows 8, incase that makes a difference.

Comment: *"From what I gethered online, setting the window to visible and requesting focus should be enough"* - Okay, first, you need to read the [JavaDocs related to `requestFocus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus--)

Comment: Second, `JFrame` is a composite component, that is, it's made up of a number components, so it's unlikely that the frame itself could become the direct key board focus owner. A more reliable solution to the problem would be to use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Swing threads issues and how initMain is called matters. Please provide more code. Btw please take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok nvm, got the focus to work via requestFocusInWindow (which also didn't work previously). Seems like the problem was requesting focus too early and only once. Why the mainframe focus didn't work either I still don't quite get, but that doesn't matter now I guess. Thanks anyways for your answers.

Comment: Understand that even `requestFocusInWindow` is unreliable for the purpose you are trying to use it for, there are any number of conditions under which it might (seemingly randomly) fail. The answer your question is to use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which solves this fundamental issue with `KeyListener`